# Excel VBA - Range Method Failed if called from VBS

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I am getting a very weird error and I've spent hours trying to figure what it is so maybe someone here will have an idea!

I am running a tool to process some data everyday and it's all working fine. To save a bit of time, I've scheduled a Windows task to run automaticaly a .VBS which is opening my tool and running the code.

The code fails on the 1st line of the below section (Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed):

```
With Range("OTBTota")
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C/R[10]C"
    .Value2 = .Value2
End With
```

The thing is, this part of code is among a long list of ranges where I am doing the exact same thing (which is working just fine) and when I am running it from the Excel directly, it works....!

Why would this specific Range fails when I am running this code from a VBS?
Here is another hint: if I run this VB script again when I already have an Excel process running in the background (e.g. after I get the bug and close the VB Editor), then it works fine...!

Could this come from my VB Script? Here is the code:

```
Dim xlApp, xlBook  

  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
  xlApp.Application.Visible = False

  Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\User1\TEST.xlsm", 0, False)

  xlBook.Application.Run "AUTO_Update_All_A"

  xlBook.Save
  xlBook.Close
  xlApp.Quit

  Set xlBook = Nothing
  Set xlApp = Nothing
```

It really doesn't make any sense to me but my VB knowledge is quite limited so I might be missing something obvious.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: it wouldn't hurt to specify the `worksheet` before `range` on that line so for example: `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("insert sheet name").Range("OTBTota")`

Comment: Is `OTBTota` correct or a typo?

Comment: Could be wrong, but it sounds to me like it crashed at some point and a process may still have it open.  As a test, close all your open excel instances.  Go to task manager and see if you still have Excel processes active.  If you do stop them. (If you have a lot of them open command prompt `taskkill /IM Excel.exe /F`).  Then try running your script again.  If it still doesn't work I was wrong.. :)

Comment: @ Jeeped: not a typo, it's working fine when runing it manually.
@ Kubie: it's already done. I didn't post the full code, but I am using "With Workbook("WorkbookName").Worksheet("WorksheetName")" before arriving to this part of the code
@JosephC : I don't have any other Excel process runing. But the point is, when I have one after my process crash the first time, the issue doesn't come up.
I did not find any explanation but changed my code to work around this issue for now.